# Looping through list for each element computation in R

Tags: r, list, for-loop

I am naive at R and trying to get a stuff done so advanced apologies if it is a stupid way of doing it.

I am trying to get coefficient and relevance of x-values to y-values. Values in X are criteria to which co-relevance is being tested. 
I need to find postive or negative relevance/confidence for results represented in `myList`. Rather than putting one column in Y manually I just want to iterate through it for result of each column.

```
    library(rms)
    parameters <- read.csv(file="C:/Users/manjaria/Documents/Lek papers/validation_csv.csv", header=TRUE)
    #attach(parameters)

    myList <- c("name1","name2","name3","name4","name5")
    for (cnt in seq(length(myList))) {
    Y<- cbind(myList[cnt])
    X<- cbind(age,female,income,employed,traveldays,modesafety,prPoolsize)
    XVar <-c("age","female","income","employed","traveldays","modesafety","prPoolsize")

    summary (Y)
    summary (X)

    table(Y)

    ddist<- datadist(XVar)
options(datadist = 'ddist')
ologit<- lrm(Y ~ X, data = parameters)

    print(ologit)

    fitted<- predict(ologit, newdata=parameters, type = "fitted.ind")
    colMeans(fitted)
    }
```

I encounter:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = Y ~ X, data = parameters, na.action = function (frame)  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'X')
```

If I don't loop through for-loop and use a static name for Y like
`Y<- cbind(name1)` it works well.

Comment: What is your question? What is your goal? Can you share a reproducible example? We don't have the `CSV` file on your C drive.

Comment: @Gregor Hi Sorry for lack of clarity. I have edited question. Hope it help. Let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: I still can't run your code because I don't have the CSV. It seems like you're sharing a lot of extra code. Is `summary (Y)` important to your question? What about `table(Y)`? It seems like this could be deleted without losing anything - so why are you sharing it? You should try to share a **minimal working example**. With the extra code your example is *not minimal*, without the CSV your example is *not working*.

Comment: I'm also confused by your last line: "If I use ... `cbind()` it works well" makes it sound like you have the solution. If `cbind` works instead of a `for` loop, is that your solution?